# Using Lax Milgram lemma and energy estimates on the real line

Tags: functional-analysis, boundary-value-problem, riesz-representation-theorem, elliptic-operators

I just want to check something. I want to use the energy estimates on the real line for an elliptic operator $L$ acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. (The energy estimates are related to the Lax-Mi

[https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aram/weak.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Earam/weak.pdf) (Slide 17)

The equation is given as $Lu = 0$, and $u$ has boundary conditions $u \longrightarrow 0$ as $x \longrightarrow \infty$. Furthermore, the domain of the operator is $L:D(L) \rightarrow X$ where $D(L) = H_0^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap H^2(\mathbb{R})$.

The reason why I am apprehensive about using this is largely from the use of the Poincare inequality that doesn't work on $\mathbb{R}$. My understanding however is that I should be able to use the energy estimates though.

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you are trying to ask. The Lax-Milgram theorem works in any Hilbert space. What exactly is your question?

Comment: An elliptic operator is being on an open sub space $u$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Is that my case?

Comment: If $H$ is a (real) Hilbert space, you can define an elliptic/coercive operator $A \colon H \to H$ via there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that $(A x, x)_H \ge \alpha \, \|x\|_H^2$ for all $x \in H$. The Lax-Milgram lemma applies in this situation.